# App engine: generating a search index. Does anyone have simpler code that breaks down how to build an index?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, search

I went through the documentation and tried to follow the code examples on github, but I'm still confused.

Is this the procedure?

1) Generate an index:

```
index = search.Index(name = "geoSearch")
```

2) Define fields:

```
ID = #my ID
geopoint = #a lat long coordinate
fields = [
        search.TextField(name = "ID", value = ID),
        search.GeoField(name = "location" , value = geopoint) ]
```

3) Create a document to store fields:

```
doc = search.Document(fields = fields)
```

4) Then I'll iterate through, and add "fields" to my document one a time like so:

```
search.Index(name = "geoSearch").add(doc)
```

And once I finish iterating through, then I'll have a search index? Does this seem reasonable? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Note that you also need an index configuration file:
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/indexconfig